# Parent does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uwp

My code is

```
 namespace classlibrary
 {
   public class numerictext : EditText
    {
      //My code

    }
```

When I try to inherit a edit text control in a class library, I'm getting the error: Parent does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. I understand the problem is that Parent has no constructor with 0 arguments. But how to inherit a control in a class library?

Comment: does your numerictext have a constructor?  What does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call one of the base constructors in your derived class. Assuming you are using the Android [`EditText`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.EditText/) widget:

```
public class numerictext : EditText
{
    public numerictext(Context context) : base(context)
                                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                                      //Note how we are now calling the base constructure
    {
        //empty or you can add your own code
    }

    public numerictext(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For any Android-based View subclass, you need to supply the three constructors that call their base object constructors, ie.:

```
public class MyView : EditText
{
    public MyView(Context context) : base(context) { }
    public MyView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) { }
    public MyView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle) { }

    // your override code....
}
```

Comment: Technically there a 5 constructors, but you don't need to supply them all.

Comment: @DavidG yes, you are correct, but the three listed are the ones that are used in `Xamarin.Android`-based JNI/NDK apps

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered changing EditText to:

```
public class EditTtext 
{
   data stuff..
   EditText() {}

   other functions
}
```

Though I don't see why yours wouldn't work as is

Comment: I want to create numeric text box in android.I need to create the control in class library by inheriting edit text. When i try to inherit , i'm getting the error.

Comment: The EditText class he's using is a Xamarin Forms control. He needs to subclass a control, and for that call the correct base constructors.